# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: java, android, swiperefreshlayout

i added to my code `swipelayoutrefresh` to refresh news in `RecyclerView` when i scroll under the screen of my device; but when i run my project i get this error:

> "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML
>   file line #17: Error inflating class
>   android.support.v7.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout".

WHY?

I hope that you can help me!

THANKS IN ADVANCE EVERYBODY!

**MAIN ACTIVITY:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       // refreshLayout=(SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        ReadRss readRss=new ReadRss(this,recyclerView);
        readRss.execute();

      /*  refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener(){
            @Override
            public void onRefresh(){
                ReadRss readRss=new ReadRss(getApplication(),recyclerView);

                readRss.execute();
            }
        });*/
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                int topRowVerticalPosition =
                        (recyclerView == null || recyclerView.getChildCount() == 0) ? 0 : recyclerView.getChildAt(0).getTop();
                refreshLayout.setEnabled(topRowVerticalPosition >= 0);
                ReadRss readRss=new ReadRss(getApplication(),recyclerView);

                readRss.execute();

            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**LOGCAT:**

```
09-27 12:02:05.966 14491-14491/com.example.rssreader E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.rssreader, PID: 14491
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rssreader/com.example.rssreader.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3256)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3352)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
at com.example.rssreader.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3209)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3352) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:843)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
at com.example.rssreader.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3209) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3352) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.rssreader-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.rssreader-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1001) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:843) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
at com.example.rssreader.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3209) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3352) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

**CONTENT MAIN:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.rssreader.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        />
    <android.support.v7.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**GRADLE:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rssreader"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
}
```

Comment: please post your xml layout and app gradle file. May be you are using v4 library rather than v7.

Comment: ok, i just added grade and layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SwipeRefreshLayout is in the v4 support lib, not v7. Change to

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Also see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html

Comment: Try to implement it the right way. SwipeRefreshLayout is not something you can randomly put somewhere. See an example here for reference https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/implementing-swipe-to-refresh/

Comment: but i need an example with recycleview not list view

Comment: I don't think there is a difference. But you can find examples on google

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the version from 23 to 24 in build.gradle.

I have a similar problem, when I change the all version from 23 to 24. no error information display.

```
Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class android.widget.RadioButton
```